The sum of distances from a vertex in G to all other vertices has constant parity

Let $G$ be a tree on an even number of vertices. Prove that the sum of distances from a vertex $v \in V(G)$, to all other vertices has same parity.

This question was already asked on MSE here, but I wish to prove this using induction (if possible).
Here is my attempt:
Clearly, the hypothesis holds for $n=2$ vertices. Assume the hypothesis holds for some tree $T$ with $k$ vertices. Consider the tree $T'$ constructed by joining two vertices $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ to some vertices of $T$. Clearly $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ must be pendant vertices. All we must prove now that $d(u_{1},v)+d(u_{2},v)$ must have same parity for all $v \in V(T)$.
Conjecture:
Let G be a Tree with even number of vertices. The sum of distances from any two pendant vertices of $G$ to any other vertex in $G$ has constant parity.
I checked this statement for small number of vertices, it seems to hold. But is it true generally? Is there a simple proof?

Here's a proof of your conjecture, which will provide what you need for your inductive idea.
Let $u, v$ be leaves of $G$. Since $G$ is a tree, there is a unique path between $u$ and $v$, say $P$. Let $l$ denote the length of $P$, and note that for all $w\in V(P)$ $d(w, u) = l-d(w, v)$, so $d(w, u) + d(w, v) = l$. For any vertex $x$ not in $P$, there's a unique path from $x$ to the closest vertex, say $y$, on $P$. Then $$d(x, u) + d(x, v) = d(x, y)+d(y, u)+d(x, y)+d(y, v) = l+2d(x, y).$$
Thus, for all $x\in V(G)$, the parity of $d(x, u) + d(x, v)$ is the same as that of $l$, in particular, is constant.
In fact, the above argument works for any vertices $u, v \in V(G)$, not necessarily leaves.
